# Add custom Twitter REST API queries using Kotlin

Tags: android, twitter, kotlin, twitter-rest-api

I'm a newbie in Kotlin.
I'm building an app like Twitter.
I want to create custom class extends TwitterApiClient - to use more endpoints. Twitter's tutorial is here
[Tutorial](https://twittercommunity.com/t/adding-custom-queries-android/34542)

Here's my code:

```
class TwitterApiList(session: TwitterSession) : TwitterApiClient(session) {

    fun getHomeTimeline(): TwitterCustom {
        return getService(TwitterCustom::class.java)
    }
}
// TwitterCustom interface
public interface TwitterCustom {
    @GET("/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json")
    fun home_timeline(@Query("count") count: Int?, @Query("since_id") since_id: Int?, @Query("max_id") max_id: Int?, cb: Callback<List<Tweet>>)
}
// And how I use it
val apiClient = TwitterApiList(TwitterCore.getInstance().sessionManager.activeSession)
apiClient.getHomeTimeline().home_timeline(null, null, null, object : Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
    override fun success(result: Result<List<Tweet>>?) {
        Log.d("result", result.toString())
    }

    override fun failure(exception: TwitterException?) {
        Log.d("failed", exception?.message)
    }
})
```

When I run app, it’s always crash with message “Service methods cannot return void.” at this line

```
apiClient.getHomeTimeline().home_timeline(null, null, null, object : Callback<List<Tweet>>()
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you all.

Comment: maybe cose ur ```fun home_timeline``` returns Unit (void)?

Comment: @qwert_ukg maybe it's the problem. But I don't know how to write this function to return something - after that implement it to use Callback function.

Comment: just try to add return type

Comment: what is the full declaration of Callback<T>?

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is calling methods that return `Unit`.  I.e. `success()` has no return value, `Log.d` returns `Unit`, so the `Unit` is implied.  Same goes for `failure()`.

Look closer at the Callback class.  If you have and IDE with "Intelli-sense" or the like, it will help you.  Otherwise, look at the interface/class and determine how the methods are defined, specifically, look at the return type and either change your calls to match or change the `Callback<T>` methods to be Unit (assuming it is your interface).  [This link](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html) can help you figure out how to write your functions to return specific types.

Let's say you find something like this...

```
interface Callback<T> {
    fun success(result: Result<T>) : T //notice the : T determines the type of the function
    //... other members
}
```

Then your code might look like this...

```
apiClient.getHomeTimeline().home_timeline(null, null, null, object : Callback<List<Tweet>>() {
    override fun success(result: Result<List<Tweet>>?) {
        Log.d("result", result.toString())
        return result.getMemberForT() // I made up the name, would need
                                      // decl. for Result<T> 
    }
    //...
}
```

But without the declarations for Callback and Result, I would only be guessing.